# Cant autowire DataSource

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

i have some simple application, and i have the problem with this class(it's only a part)

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class AppUserDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    @Autowired
    public AppUserDAO(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
```

here is build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.2.4.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When i start my app, i get next :

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.dao.AppUserDAO required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'dataSource' in 'JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' in 'XADataSourceAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

I'm new in Spring and cant understand what i should do.

p.s. Also, here is my apllication.properties for database( if its needed). I dont know why but postgresql.Driver underscored with red as a mistake.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=12345
```

p.p.s. I read some another topics with similar problem and it didnt help me.

Comment: Are you using SpringBoot ?

Comment: yes, i use template from spring initilizer, added build.gradle to question

Comment: I cant read gradle build files since I just used maven. But of the top I can understand dependencies are defined under dependencies. So there you have to add the dependency of the Postgres Driver. Without the driver, it cannot connect to the database. Add the Postgres SQL driver in the build file and rebuit. Be sure to include the correct version.

Comment: thx, added driver for database, but now have some other problem.. think i will fix it. Thank you one more time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `build.gradle` is missing two dependencies:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc - to get TransactionManager, DataSource etc
- org.postgresql:postgresql - to load PostgreSQL driver